# Run processing PApplet in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, processing

Here is the code:

```
import processing.core._
import PConstants._
import PApplet._

class PApp extends PApplet{
  args = Array("PApp")
  var x: Float = 0.0f
  var y: Float = 0.0f
  var z: Float = 0.0f

  override def setup(): Unit = {
    size(200, 200, "P3D")
    x = width/2
    y = height/2
    z = 0
  }

  override def draw(): Unit = {
    translate(x, y, z)
    rectMode(CENTER)
    rect(0, 0, 10, 10)
    z += 1
  }
}
```

If I try to run this (ctrl-shift-R in intellij), I get this message:

```
Usage: PApplet [options] <class name> [sketch args]
See the Javadoc for PApplet for an explanation.
```

And no graphics appear. How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with scala, but I have been playing around with Processing 3 quite a bit. Are you just trying to launch a sketch, or are you trying to embed it as an applet component?

Comment: Any solutions so far?

Answer (score 6):

You should fill up the "Program arguments:" option inside the Run Configuration.
This is like this option is set up in my case:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the error message:

> Usage: PApplet [options] <class name> [sketch args]

This means that when PApplet runs, it needs at least one argument - `<class name>` - the full class-path of your sketch.  The `options` and `Sketch Args` are optional, as indicated by the square braces.

So, if you have a sketch like this:

```
package com.something.nice;

public class MySketch extends PApplet
{
    ...
}
```

Then, you'll need to pass `com.something.nice.MySketch` as an argument to your application.

In IntelliJ IDEA, you do this in your build configuration (via the menu: Run -> Edit Configurations...), in the "Program arguments" field.

This requirement was a result of the [changes from Processing v2 to v3](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0).

> Applet is gone — Java's java.awt.Applet is no longer the base class
>   used by PApplet, so any sketches that make use of Applet-specific
>   methods (or assume that a PApplet is a Java AWT Component object) will
>   need to be rewritten.

You may also want to take note of this (same doc):

> A new settings() method that is called behind the scenes. Most users
>   will never notice this, but if you're using Processing without its
>   preprocessor (i.e. from Eclipse or a similar development environment),
>   then put any calls to size(), fullScreen(), smooth(), noSmooth(), and
>   pixelDensity() into that method. More information can be found in the
>   reference. Only users who are in other development environments should
>   use settings(). It shouldn't be used for any other purpose.